# Uniform continuity regarding union of open sets

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

I am stuck at the following Real Analysis problem from my book:

**Problem:** Give an example of two open sets $A$ and $B$ and a continuous function $f: A \cup B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f\mid A$ and $f\mid B$ are uniformly continuous, but f is **not** uniformly continuous.

**What have i tried?**

I know that $f(x) = x^{2}$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is not uniformly continuous. With that in mind, i tried to solve the problem.

First, observe that $f\mid (0,1)$ is uniformly continuous (since f is Lipschitz in the bounded open interval $(0,1)$.

**Now i am stuck.** I am trying to choose the set $B$ as to obtain what was required in the problem, but i just cannot do it. Every time i pick an open interval $B$ such that $f\mid B$ is uniformly continuous, $f: A \cup B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ also turns out to be uniformly continuous, thus not passing the test.

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance, Lucas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $A = (0, 1),$ $B = (-1, 0),$ and $f:A \cup B \to \Bbb R$ given by

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x + 1 & x > 0, \\ x - 1 & x < 0. \end{cases}$$

It is clear that $f \mid A$ is uniformly continuous. ($\delta = \epsilon$ works.) The same is true for $f \mid B$.

However, for $f$ on $A \cup B$, note that if we choose $\epsilon = 1$, then no matter which $\delta > 0$ is given, we can find $\eta > 0$ small enough so that $2\eta < \delta$ and $f(\eta) - f(-\eta) > 1$. Conclude from this.

Comment: I am just a little confused regarding the proof as to why $f$ on $A \cup B$ is uniformly continuous. Doesn't one have to consider also the case where $\eta$ is less than or equal to zero?

Comment: Is it correct to argue that $f \mid A$ is uniformly continuous since it is Lipschitz with constant $c = 1$?

Comment: $f$ on $A \cup B$ is *not* uniformly continuous, as was the intent of the post. Yes, that argument regarding Lipschitz continuity is correct.

Comment: Why did you write $f(-\eta)$? I dont get the minus sign. In fact, I am also confused as to why $2 \eta<\delta$. I dont understand the values chosen for x and y

Comment: I'm choosing $\eta > 0$ in such a way that $2\eta < \delta$. For example, you can choose $\eta = \delta/4$. In this case, for $x = \eta$ and $y = -\eta$, you have $|x - y| < \delta$. Note that $f(\eta) - f(-\eta) = 2 + 2\eta > 1$. That is, $|f(x) - f(y)| > \epsilon$.

Comment: One last question: How can you guarantee that $x$ and $y$ both belong to the domain $A \cup B$?

Comment: You're right, I should've mentioned $\eta = \min\{\delta/4, 1/2\}$ in my previous comment. That's why in my original post, I said "$\eta$ ... small enough". On the other hand, I could've simply taken $A = (0, \infty)$ and $B = (-\infty, 0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let$$A=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N,\ n\text{ odd}}\left(\frac1{n+1},\frac1n\right)\quad\text{and}\quad B=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N,\ n\text{ even}}\left(\frac1{n+1},\frac1n\right).$$Define $f\colon A\cup B\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ with$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }x\in A\\0&\text{ if }x\in B.\end{cases}$$Then $f|_A$ and $f|_B$ are constant and therefore continuous. But $f$ is not uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 0):

What about $A=]0,1[$, $B=]1,2[$ and $f$ such that $f(x) =  x$ if $x\in ]0,1[$ and $f(x) = x+1$ if $x\in ]1,2[$?

$f$ is continuous on $A\cup B$, but clearly not uniformly since for $x_n = 1-1/n$ and $y_n = 1+1/n$, $x_n-y_n\rightarrow 0$, but $f(y_n)-f(x_n) \geqslant 1$ for all $n$.